# Copying Battlefield 3 files to new machine

Tags: battlefield-3

Im upgrading my Processor from Intel Q9550 to AMD FX 8350, so its surly going have to format my C drive, and re-installing Windows 7 again.

While my Battlefield 3 setup (origin) is on D drive.

Will it still work when I re-install win 7 again ? Or Do i Need to take any registry backup, if any how.

Please guide me. And I hope when re-install Origin again on new machine the copied files should work.

More details.
My current Origin path: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Origin`

[image]

Comment: You shouldent need to back it up. It should work perfect, since your dont touch the D: drive at all. But you can back it up if it makes you feel better though. I cant see why I shouldent work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Take backup of Battlefield 3 folder (That is inside Origin).
2. Install Origin client, start downloading game, and then pause. You can see it made new Battlefield folder.
3. Delete the new battlefield folder, and just replace with the old one and resume downloading.. it will start installing the game and done within a minute.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, you'll always be able to re-install Battlefield 3.

Origin works quite like Steam, all your games on there is avaible for download again.
That means, if you have Origin installed, but not Battlefield, you can always download it through Origin.

Just login on Origin using your username/mail and password, click on the Battlefield 3 cover and hit "Download". That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you think that changing your CPU is going to force your hard drive to be reformatted?

You can change any physical component of your machine(motherboard, ram, cpu video card etc) and not have to reformat your hard drive.

Comment: Hi.
Yes, that will only work if im using the same specs. But Im installing AMD system now and new mobo too. I just installed new system, had to re-install Windows 7, since win7 was unable to run with new specs. (Im replying to u from my new machine, i removed old cpu and mobo.)

I have taken backup, since its already in D drive. I will update again, on how i fixed it.

Comment: @STEEL - You didnt have to reinstall Windows there was a solution to the problem you experienced.

Comment: @Ramhound can u pls tell me how to configure new hardware with old windows setup ? thats wud be gr8 :)